# Force unsubscribe from a Kik bot

Tags: kik

Is there any way my bot can unsubscribe people from itself?

It apparently has 11 subscribers (from a maxiumum of 10) so nobody new can chat to it. I'd like to clear out those subscribers, and I see references to unsubscribe in the API (although that may refer to not-yet-subscribed?) but I see no way to kick off these subscribers. Are they fixed for the life of the bot?

I see I can remove the subscriber limit by getting approved in the bot shop, I'll start that process but guess it will take a while.

Am I doomed until then? Or I have to register a new bot every 10 users?